# Bold font in Label with setBold method

Tags: python, pyqt4

Can't make Bold font for label. What is wrong with my code?

```
self.label = QtGui.QLabel('Bla', self)
self.label.setFont(QtGui.QFont.setBold(True))
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`setBold` is a method of `QFont`: it needs an instance of `QFont`. You can't call directly `QtGui.QFont.setBold()`, because there is nothing to be set to bold.

You have to first create the `QFont` object, then set it to bold, then set it as the label's font.

```
myFont=QtGui.QFont()
myFont.setBold(True)
self.label.setFont(myFont)
```

---

Note that `self.label.setFont(QtGui.QFont().setBold(True))` wouldn't work either, because `setBold` returns `None`.

If you'd like a one-liner, `QFont` can be [created with arguments](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfont.html#QFont-2), and one of them is the weight. For a bold Times font:

```
self.label.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times",weight=QtGui.QFont.Bold))
```

Answer (score 15):

```
self.label.setStyleSheet("font-weight: bold")
```

easier I believe